# get value from UniformParameterPtr in Ogre

Tags: c++, data-structure, ogre

I have a variable of type `UniformParameterPtr` decalared by `Ogre` and I want to get its value.
What is the right way to this?
I tried the method `.get()` but it doesn't really give the value.
 something else?

Answer (score 1):

`UniformParameterPtr` is a typedef for `Ogre::SharedPtr<UniformParameter>`. With `Ogre::SharedPtr` the behavior is always the same:

You can retrieve the actual object instance that is encapsulated in the shared pointer via `get()`, which would in your case give you an `UniformParameter` instance.

Alternatively you can directly access the members of the object encapsulated in the shared pointer via `->` as if it were a regular pointer.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it didnt work.  
I need to get the `alpharejectfunction` value from `  mPSAlphaFunc` ?
can you show me the code to do this?